# Rendering results are corrupting between blocks

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, image

I recently updated Blender from 2.74 to 2.76b and I've been getting buggy rendering results with Blender render. Images are corrupting between rendering blocks and strange vertical cracks are shown in result.

[image: Bug]

Editing is ok in 3D view with rendered viewport:

[image]

I've uploaded a minimum set of .blend file to demonstrate this:

http://1drv.ms/1KPbZef

When I render this project as an image, I get following result:

[image: result]

Then, how can I fix this? Is this bug, or just misconfiguration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just switch to perspective camera:

[image]

And your Render will look normal:

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works! After that I found [the documentation](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/camera/lens.html#panoramic) describes that panoramic camera is only supported in the Cycles render engine...

Answer (score 2):

Under render panel you may want to turn on

1. Anti-Aliasing and check "Full Samples.
2. Use Gaussian filter mode.
3. Move your model away from the floor so that it is not intersecting directly on the floor plane.

   [image]

Hope that helps.

**Extra Note** The blender 2.76b on my end do not display any serious anti-aliasing as shown on the images you posted. Hence I am not very sure if the problem could infact be caused by hardware.